# Create a verbatim mdframed environment

Tags: environments, verbatim, mdframed

I'd like to use and `mdframed` environment with `verbatim` in it. I've read the both documentations, googled but I've found nothing regarding this matter.

MWE below:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,pdftex]{geometry}
\usepackage[headings]{fullpage}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.90}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage[framemethof=tikz,%
innerleftmargin=\parindent,%
linewidth=0pt,%
backgroundcolor=shadecolor,%
skipabove=0.6\baselineskip,%
skipbelow=0.6\baselineskip]{mdframed}


% How to create a new environment that uses mdframed and verbatim?
\newenvironment{magic}
{\begin{mdframed}}
{\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed} % How to make these
\begin{verbatim} % two into one?
From: torva...@klaava.Helsinki.FI (Linus Benedict Torvalds)
Newsgroups: comp.os.minix
Subject: What would you like to see most in minix?
Summary: small poll for my new operating system
Keywords: 386, preferences
Message-ID: <1991Aug25.205708.9541@klaava.Helsinki.FI>
Date: 25 Aug 91 20:57:08 GMT
Organization: University of Helsinki
Lines: 20


Hello everybody out there using minix -

I'm doing a (free) operating system (just a hobby, won't be big and
professional like gnu) for 386(486) AT clones.  This has been brewing
since april, and is starting to get ready.  I'd like any feedback on
things people like/dislike in minix, as my OS resembles it somewhat
(same physical layout of the file-system (due to practical reasons)
among other things). 

I've currently ported bash(1.08) and gcc(1.40), and things seem to work.
This implies that I'll get something practical within a few months, and
I'd like to know what features most people would want.  Any suggestions
are welcome, but I won't promise I'll implement them :-)

        Linus (torva...@kruuna.helsinki.fi)

PS.  Yes - it's free of any minix code, and it has a multi-threaded fs.
It is NOT protable (uses 386 task switching etc), and it probably never
will support anything other than AT-harddisks, as that's all I have :-(.
\end{verbatim} % How to make these
\end{mdframed} % two into one?

\end{document}
```

*P.S.* I don't want to use the `listings` package, because I can set margins and stuff with `mdframed` perfectly, and I don't need code highlighting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following works perfectly for me:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,pdftex]{geometry}
\usepackage[headings]{fullpage}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.90}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz,%
innerleftmargin=\parindent,%
linewidth=0pt,%
backgroundcolor=gray,%
skipabove=0.6\baselineskip,%
skipbelow=0.6\baselineskip]{mdframed}


% How to create a new environment that uses mdframed and verbatim?
\newenvironment{magic}
{\begin{mdframed}}
{\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed} % How to make these
\begin{verbatim}

\end{verbatim} % How to make these
\end{mdframed} % two into one?
  <snip>
\end{document}
```

Note that I corrected your typo: `framemethof` vs `framemethod` and I changed the color that is being used. The error it gave me: `Package pgfbase Error: Unsupported color model '0'. Sorry \end{mdframed}`. I doubt that this is related to the combination of `mdframed` and `verbatim`. Since I get the same error when I replace the `verbatim` environment with some text.

**Edit:** Marco's comment made me realize I had misunderstood the question. I now assume uou are mainly concerned with getting a new environment that works as verbatim inside of mdframed. You can use the construct suggested by Marco in the comment along with creating a new environment for `verbatim`. The following code:

```
\newenvironment{myverb}
{\endgraf\verbatim}
{\endverbatim}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{myverb}{\begin{mdframed}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{myverb}{\end{mdframed}}
```

In your document you can then use `\begin{myverb} ...\end{myverb}` to get a `verbatim` inside of an `mdframed` environment.

Comment: Please see the example file [mdframed-example-texsx.pdf](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed) to see how you can work with `\BeforBeginEnvironment` (Example 1)

Comment: Few minutes ago I uploaded version 1.2 to CTAN. Now you can simple use `\surroundwithmdframed{verbatim}`. With the files of github you can test it.